# How to make the transfer window closes when the data is really fully copied ? (windows fakes speed, and continue copy in background)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, file-transfer, resource-monitor

When I copy a 50GB file from my SSD to a HDD, *Windows* shows the transfer window,

it shows transfer speed at 800MB/s

and closes the transfer window once at 100%

except I know my HDD can't copy at 800MB/s obviously

and when I watch the Resource Monitor:

it shows *Windows* is still transferring data to the HDD at 70MB/s (the real speed of the HDD)

even though the transfer window has been closed for a while.

---

**is there a way to stop *Windows* from faking transfer rate ?**
*(I read once, somewhere, that you can make it stop using the RAM, but then the OS has a hard time with copying many tiny files, the transfer rate is horrible then)*

**or to stop *Windows* from closing the transfer window before the copy is really done ?**

Comment: Its not "faking."  Its called cache.  Windows uses RAM to cache reading and writing.  Even your hard drive has its own cache.  Why would you want to disable it?  It actually makes your computer faster.

Comment: @Keltari imagine you have a tiny SSD and a HDD
you copy a big file to the HDD, Windows says it's finished, then you launch a game that is on the HDD, the whole computer will lag because Windows is trying to access a lot of files (games) and copying a big file in the background. it doesn't just get 2x slower, but 10x or even 20x slower.
and this is just ONE example, I have many others.

Answer (score 1):

Windows normally uses up to half of the memory for caching disk files.

This means that when copying, Windows at first reads and writes very
fast the data, but that is an illusion since the data is only copied
to memory.
When the memory cache is full, Windows then has to wait for some writes
to the disk to physically terminate in order to liberate cache space,
which is when the slow-down starts to be felt.

The copy operation will be done in spurts:
Reading quickly to memory, then wait, repeating itself again until the
copy is finished.
The displayed speed in this phase depends on the amount of memory of
the computer, the more memory there is, the more visible are the spikes.

This behavior is built-into Windows and cannot be changed.

Some file-copy products can get better speeds by avoiding using
the Windows cache.

One such product is
[FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/),
which is the fastest copy program I know.